# Should I use inline hyperlinks or put the links at the bottom of the post?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Is there a preferred way to insert hyperlinks?

Should I use the button in the editor, which puts the links to the bottom of the post:

```
[Link][1]

[1]: http://www.example.com
```

or the "inline" way:

```
[Link](http://www.example.com)
```

where the link is put directly into the brackets inside the text?

Comment: Whichever way works best for you? It really doesn't matter.

Comment: I usually do it manually. You can do it as you wish. BTW, The third way would be CTRL+L.

Comment: It is simpler for me.. but makes the post unclear if someone wants to edit it.

Comment: That's a fair point, hadn't thought of that. But I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: I edited your question to make your meaning clearer, feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: I like the edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, use whichever way works best for you.

You have a point, though, that  the format with the links at the bottom (forming a sort of bibliography) makes long-term quality-checking easier. Especially with long and/or popular answers, it is the best way to go.

Comment: Well, that's trading ease of checking link-rot for appropriateness. I'm not convinced that's a win. Might work a bit better if the links get a descriptive name instead of a number though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I prefer to have the link where I use it, so I don't have to look it up at the end somewhere later.

Also, for links to SE, I mostly prefer bare links, which are rendered with a title-lookup.

Naturally, for embedding pictures, automatic links are the way to go, unless the image is already online at a stable location...

---

But that's just my preference, do whatever works best for your work-flow.